# Как запретить перерисовку компонента в Java?

Tags: java, swing

Каким методом это можно реализовать? Перерисовка должна быть запрещена у конкретного экземпляра класса, а не у всего класса.

Расскажу ситуацию. Я создаю несколько экземпляров класса `Graph`. При создании нового экземпляра я вызываю на него `repaint()` и `update(getGraphics())`. При этом все старые объекты перерисовываются по параметрам нового, а это мне не нужно. Как запретить их перерисовку?

UPD: Обнаружил, что при вызове update(getGraphics()) создается еще один экземпляр Graph. Почему так происходит?

Код:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));

    colIndex++;
    Color c = Color.black;

    switch(colIndex){
        case 0: {c = Color.red;break;}
        case 1: {c = Color.orange;break;}
        case 2: {c = Color.green;break;}
        case 3: {c = Color.CYAN;break;}
        case 4: {c = Color.blue;break;}
        case 5: {c = Color.MAGENTA;break;}
        case 6: {c = Color.black;break;}
        case 7: {c = Color.red;colIndex = 0;break;}
    }

    g2d.setColor(c);

    int GrX1=0;
    int GrY1=0;
    int GrX2;
    int GrY2;

    for(int i1 = 0;i1<(GraphDrawer.x2-GraphDrawer.x1);i1++) {
        switch (funcvar) {
            case 'x': {varvalue = (double) -10 + i1*GraphDrawer.xUnit;break;}
            case 'y': {varvalue = (double) -10 + i1*GraphDrawer.yUnit;break;}
        }


        switch (funcvar) {
        case 'x':GrX2 = (int) Math.round((result+10)*21);
                 GrY2 = (int) Math.round((-varvalue+10)*21);
                 if (GrX1!=0||GrY1!=0){
                     g2d.drawLine(GrX1,GrY1,GrX2,GrY2);
                 }
                 GrX1 = GrX2;
                 GrY1 = GrY2;
                 break;
        case 'y':GrX2 = (int) Math.round((varvalue+10)*21);
                 GrY2 = (int) Math.round((-result+10)*21);

                 if (GrX1!=0||GrY1!=0){
                     g2d.drawLine(GrX1,GrY1,GrX2,GrY2);
                 }



                 GrX1 = GrX2;
                 GrY1 = GrY2;
                 break;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку. Поля класса у меня инициализировались в перерисовке, а не в конструкторе.